# Regex Optional Group Wrong Capture

Tags: regex

Given the following text:

`here is my text[my_tag]text[/my_tag]`

How can I catch `here is my text` given that `[my_tag]` is optional and might not exist at all?
I've tried:

`.*(\[my_tag\].*\[\/my_tag\])?`

Yet it catches everything including the tag itself instead of just `here is my text`

Any ideas?

Comment: which regex engine are you using?

Comment: `^(.*?)(\[my_tag\][^\]\[]*\[\/my_tag\])?$`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew ! I used:
^(.*?)(\[my_tag\].*\[\/my_tag\])?$

Comment: Yeah, in this case, it will work. In case you have other tags, it won't. If you have nested tags, neither will, you will need a DOM parser.